# SlickGrid Selenium Automation Issues

Tags: selenium-webdriver, slickgrid

I am trying to interact with slick grid and I used the below code

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

```
    //Returns the DIV element matching class grid-canvas, which contains every data row currently being rendered in the DOM.
    WebElement rowCount = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return grid.getCanvasNode();");
```

but it is returning the error saying grid not defined.

I figured out that I have to define the grid for getting the above code to work.

The definition of the grid is as below which has to be defined

```
 var grid;
  var columns = [
    {id: "Date", name: "Date", field: "Date"},
    {id: "tpn", name: "tpn", field: "tpn"},
  ];
  var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: true,
    explicitInitialization: true
  };


$(function () {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      data[i] = {
        Date: "20180612",
SPN:Math.random(),
      };

var myGrid = $("<div id='MovementTracker' style='height: 399px; overflow: hidden; outline: 0px; position: relative;'></div>");

grid = new Slick.Grid(myGrid, data, columns, options);

 myGrid.appendTo($("#app > div > div > div > div > div.size--5.padding--horizontal--double > div.size--content > div > div > div"));
 grid.init();
```

As the definition is multiline, I am struck here how to execute this multiline javascript code in selenium to make grid initialised.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is all about Javascript scope.
I know SlickGrid, but not Selenium. The `grid` variable is presumably a member of `Document` because it's not explicitly scoped. If Selenium executes in a different scope, you'd have to reference it as a member of `Document`. But it depends on the order of creation of the various scopes and objects.